# Why this is not correctly printing the username i entered?

Tags: c

In this code i store username entered by user in 1-d array in struct but when i print this username it cannot print it right.

## CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct ng
{
    char username[32];
}ng;
void print();
int main()
{
    ng a;
    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",a.username);
    print();
}
void print(void)
{
    ng a;
    printf("Username: %s",a.username);
}
```

## OUTPUT:

Look at the output i enter "George" and it cannot be printed.

```
Enter Username: Geroge
Username: 
--------------------------------
Process exited after 8.333 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: You should get a text book on C. C is notoriously difficult to learn by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You have two *different* `a` variables of type `ng`, one in each function.

You need to pass the `main` one into `print`, such as with:

```
void print(Ng *a) {
    printf("Username: %s",a->username);
}
```

and call it with:

```
print(&a);
```

Comment: Or declare it globally.

Comment: Globals are rarely a good idea. They can work but it tends not to scale well.